# XML Reading to Dictionary becomes Slower with Time

Tags: c#, xml, performance, dictionary

my **C# application reads an XML-File** of the following structure. There are about 250,000 words inside the 150mb file.

```
<word>
     <name>kick</name>
     <id>485</id>
     <rels>12:4;4256:3;754:3;1452:2;86:2;125:2;</rels>
</word>
```

I want to **read the XML-File into a Dictionary**. These are some class members of my reading class.

```
private XmlReader Reader;

public string CurrentWordName;
public int CurrentWordId;
public Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, int> CurrentRelations;
```

Here is the main method of my reading class. It just reads the next word from the file and gets the `name`, `id`, and the relationships are stored into a Dictionary.

```
CurrentWordId = -1;
CurrentWordName = "";
CurrentRelations = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, int>();

while(Reader.Read())
    if(Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element & Reader.Name == "word")
    {
        while (Reader.Read())
            if (Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element & Reader.Name == "name")
            {
                XElement Title = XElement.ReadFrom(Reader) as XElement;
                CurrentWordName = Title.Value;
                break;
            }
        while (Reader.Read())
            if (Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element & Reader.Name == "id")
            {
                XElement Identifier = XElement.ReadFrom(Reader) as XElement;
                CurrentWordId = Convert.ToInt32(Identifier.Value);
                break;
            }
        while(Reader.Read())
            if (Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element & Reader.Name == "rels")
            {
                XElement Text = XElement.ReadFrom(Reader) as XElement;
                string[] RelationStrings = Text.Value.Split(';');
                foreach (string RelationString in RelationStrings)
                {
                    string[] RelationsStringSplit = RelationString.Split(':');
                    if (RelationsStringSplit.Length == 2)
                        CurrentRelations.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,int>(CurrentWordId,Convert.ToInt32(RelationsStringSplit[0])), Convert.ToInt32(RelationsStringSplit[1]));
                }
                break;
            }
        break;
    }

if (CurrentRelations.Count < 1 || CurrentWordId == -1 || CurrentWordName == "")
     return false;
else
     return true;
```

My Windows Form has a `backgroundWorker` to read all the words.

```
private void bgReader_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ReadXML Reader = new ReadXML(tBOpenFile.Text);

    Words = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, int> ReadedRelations = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, int>();

    // reading
    while(Reader.ReadNextWord())
    {
        Words.Add(Reader.CurrentWordId, Reader.CurrentWordName);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, int> CurrentRelation in Reader.CurrentRelations)
        {
            ReadedRelations.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(CurrentRelation.Key.Key, CurrentRelation.Key.Value), CurrentRelation.Value);
        }
    }
```

By debugging I noticed that **the application starts really fast and gets slower with time**.

- 7 seconds for the first 10,000 words
- 30 minutes for the first 200,000 words
- 35 minutes for the first 220,000 words

I can't explain this behaviour! But I am sure that the words in the XML-File are the same size on average. Maybe the `Add()`-method becomes slower by dictionary lenght.

**How can I speed up my application?**

Comment: Instead of reading Node by Node look at Linq to XML

Comment: Maybe it could help to have a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>` instead and index twice instead of once with a double key. Depends on the data.

Comment: @Lloyd, how would that help improve the performance?

Comment: @svick try it for yourself and see

Comment: @harold: a `relation` is a connection between two words and has a weight wich is an integer. I used the Id of the source word and the Id of the target word as key. I think this makes sense, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, now that I've run the code, I believe this is the problem:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, int> CurrentRelation in 
         Reader.CurrentRelations)
{
    ReadedRelations.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(CurrentRelation.Key.Key, 
        CurrentRelation.Key.Value), CurrentRelation.Value);
}
```

Without that loop, it works *much* faster... which leads me to suspect that the fact that you're reading from XML is effectively a red herring.

I suspect the problem is that `KeyValuePair<,>` doesn't override `Equals` and  `GetHashCode`. I believe that if you create your own `RelationKey` value type containing two `int` values and overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals` (and implementing `IEquatable<RelationKey>`), it'll be a lot faster.

Alternatively, you could always use a `long` to store the two `int` values - a bit of a hack, but it would work pretty well. I can't test this right now, but I'll give it a go when I have more time.

Even just changing your loop to:

```
foreach (var relation in Reader.CurrentRelations)
{
    ReadedRelations.Add(relation.Key, relation.Value);
}
```

would be simpler and slightly more efficient...

EDIT: Here's a sample for a `RelationKey` struct. Simply replace all occurrences of `KeyValuePair<int, int>` with `RelationKey`, and use the `Source` and `Target` properties instead of `Key` and `Value`:

```
public struct RelationKey : IEquatable<RelationKey>
{
    private readonly int source;
    private readonly int target;

    public int Source { get { return source; } }
    public int Target { get { return target; } }

    public RelationKey(int source, int target)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is RelationKey))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((RelationKey)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return source * 31 + target;
    }

    public bool Equals(RelationKey other)
    {
        return source == other.source && target == other.target;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it already does run on a `BackgroundWorker`, that's why the method is called `bgReader_DoWork`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: First I forgot clearing the `CurrentRelations` but then I noticed. After that I posted this question. Sorry, I forgot that important part. I have updated my question code now.

Comment: @JonSkeet: How should I avoid public fields? I have another `backgroundworker` wich takes the data after reading.

Comment: @sharethis: If nothing else, you could use properties instead of fields. But it would be better to make `ReadNextWord` return a value indicating success/failure, the word, ID and relations. To be honest, it's going to be very hard to diagnose this without complete code. Ideally, convert this into a short but complete console app (easier to get going) and post that, along with a link to a sample XML file.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Does it help to upload the zipped Visual Studio solution and the XML-File? The zipped XML-File is only about 22mb.

Comment: @sharethis: Yes, if you could share that somewhere it would help - but creating a short but complete program would be even better.

Comment: I never build a console application in C# so that could take some time. Visual Studio Solution http://www.mediafire.com/?yb5zy3sw19qonja and XML-File http://www.mediafire.com/?q80uocjshqwyopv

Comment: @sharethis: Console apps are *trivial* to write - and *much* easier to use for diagnosing this kind of thing. I'll have a look at your code though.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I wrote another method for the `ReadXML` class wich reads all words. The relationships are added to the private dictionary. After all the method returns the ready dictionary at once. Without foreach loops. The problem stays the same. (Maybe it ran faster for you because the compiler ignored some "useless" tasks?) I hope that I understand you right. But `KeyValuePair` have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` impplemented, doesn't id? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx

Comment: @sharethis: It inherits implementations from `ValueType`, but that's going to be expensive.

Comment: @JonSkeet: So I need to write a class wich is deducted from `KeyValuePair`? Can you help me with this?

Comment: @sharethis: Have now implemented the `RelationKey` struct (not class) - see my answer. It's much faster now :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: THANKS!!! It runs around 5 seconds, instead of an hour! :-) I will mention you in the acknowledgments of my google science fair project if you want.

Comment: @sharethis: Up to you - I'm just happy it worked. Good luck with the rest of the project!